# Macos input file version issue

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to page a page that uploads files with WKWebView.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate

Declared in apple development document it says that WKOpenPanelParameters can be used macos10.10 +

[image]

[image]

But when I use the source in xcode, it only allows me to use 10.12+... Is there any solution for this? or another way to input file? I need this to work for all 10.10+ macos versions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are right in saying that the `WKUIDelegate` protocol is available since macOS 10.10, however the method you are trying to access has been added later with macOS 10.12 as stated in the [documentation page for the method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate/1641952-webview):

[image: Available since macOS 10.12]

To use the method you have two alternative solutions:

- Change your deployment target to macOS 10.12 or later
- Find an alternative API to do what you want on macOS 10.10 and 10.11, and wrap the call inside an `if #available(...)` block

If you are instead trying to conform to the protocol you just have to mark the method (or the whole class is applicable) with an `@available(...)` attribute as suggested by the fixit for the error.